# Changing property in one Provider changes the property in another Provider as a List Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

#### UPDATE - I actually found that it is a [Flutter Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21358).

---

I have two Providers, 1 is an EntriesProvider and another is an EntryProvider. I use my EntryProvider when creating an entry and my EntriesProvider to load all the entries saved to the database. I'm having an issue which I believe might be my understanding of how to use Providers. Once I load my database data into my EntriesProvider I load that data into a ListView. Once an item is clicked, I pass the Entry from that list into my View to populate and edit.

My issue is that when I edit the Entry without saving it, I can see the changes happening in the ListView which is not what I want. I tried clearing the EntryProvider as I believed the data belonging to that was separate from the EntriesProvider. But now I have no idea after trying multiple things. Why am I updating the list when I'm only asking the EntryProvider to update its listeners?

```dart
class EntryProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Entry _entry;
  BuildContext context;

  EntryProvider();

  Entry get getEntry {
    return _entry;
  }

  void setEntryContext(Entry entryToBeSet, BuildContext context) {
    this._entry = entryToBeSet;
    this.context = context;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearEntryContext() {
    this._entry = null;
    this.context = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addImageToEntry(String imagePath) {
    getEntry.images.add(imagePath);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeImageAt(int index) {
    getEntry.images.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addTagToEntry(String tagText) {
    getEntry.tags.add(tagText);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeTagAt(int index) {
    getEntry.tags.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> saveEntry() async {
    if (getEntry.id != null) {
      await Provider.of<EntriesProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateEntry(getEntry);
    } else {
      await Provider.of<EntriesProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .addEntry(getEntry);
    }
  }
}
```

```dart
class EntriesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Entry> _entries = [];

  EntriesProvider(this._entries);

  UnmodifiableListView<Entry> get entries => UnmodifiableListView(_entries);

  int get length => _entries.length;

  List<Entry> get getEntriesSortedByDateReversed {
    List<Entry> entriesCopy = entries;
    entriesCopy.sort((a, b) => a.entryDate.compareTo(b.entryDate));

    return entriesCopy.reversed.toList();
  }

  List<Entry> getEntries(DateTime dateTime) {
    List<Entry> entriesToBeSorted = entries
        .where(
          (entry) => DateFormat.yMMMd().format(entry.entryDate).contains(
                DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dateTime),
              ),
        )
        .toList();

    entriesToBeSorted.sort((a, b) {
      return a.entryDate.compareTo(b.entryDate);
    });

    return entriesToBeSorted;
  }
}
```

```dart
class JournalListView extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isDrawerOpen;
  final TransformData transformData;

  JournalListView(this.isDrawerOpen, this.transformData);

  @override
  _JournalListScreenState createState() => _JournalListScreenState();
}

class _JournalListScreenState extends State<JournalListView> {
  List<Entry> entries = [];
  List<Entry> filteredEntries = [];
  DateTime dateTimeSet;

  AppDataModel appDataModel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dateTimeSet = DateTime.now();
  }

  Widget _buildEntryList(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<EntriesProvider>(builder: (context, entryModel, child) {
      print(entryModel.entries);
      List<Entry> entries = entryModel.getEntries(dateTimeSet);
      return Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: 650,
          maxWidth: double.infinity,
        ),
        child: Container(
          child: entries.length > 0
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: entries.length,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        if (widget.isDrawerOpen) {
                          closeDrawer();
                        } else {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                            PageRouteBuilder(
                                transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 650),
                                pageBuilder:
                                    (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
                                  final Entry copiedEntry = entries[index]
                                      .copyWith(
                                          id: entries[index].id,
                                          title: entries[index].title,
                                          description:
                                              entries[index].description,
                                          entryDate: entries[index].entryDate,
                                          feelingOnEntry:
                                              entries[index].feelingOnEntry,
                                          images: entries[index].images,
                                          location: entries[index].location,
                                          tags: entries[index].tags,
                                          time: entries[index].time,
                                          weather: entries[index].weather);
                                  Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .setEntryContext(entry, context);
                                  return JournalEntryView(copiedEntry);
                                }),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: '${entries[index].entryDate}${entries[index].id}',
                        child: _buildEntryLayout(context, entries[index]),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              : JournalEmpty(
                  'lib/assets/emojis/empty-folder.png',
                  MyLocalizations.of(context).journalListEmpty,
                ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _buildEntryLayout(BuildContext context, Entry entry) {
    int entryLayout = appDataModel.entryLayout;
    Widget entryLayoutWidget;

    switch (entryLayout) {
      case 1:
        entryLayoutWidget = EntryCard1(entry);
        break;
      case 2:
        entryLayoutWidget = EntryCard2(entry);
        break;
      default:
        entryLayoutWidget = EntryCard1(entry);
        break;
    }

    return entryLayoutWidget;
  }

  Widget _buildCalenderStrip(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 64,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: Consumer<EntriesProvider>(
        builder: (context, entryModel, child) {
          return Calendarro(
              startDate: DateUtils.getFirstDayOfMonth(DateTime(2020, 09)),
              endDate: DateUtils.getLastDayOfCurrentMonth(),
              selectedSingleDate: DateTime.now(),
              displayMode: DisplayMode.WEEKS,
              dayTileBuilder: CustomDayBuilder(entryModel.entries),
              onTap: (datetime) {
                if (widget.isDrawerOpen) {
                  closeDrawer();
                }
                setState(() {
                  dateTimeSet = datetime;
                });
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchEntryWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<EntriesProvider>(builder: (context, entries, child) {
      return IconButton(
        onPressed: () => showSearch(
          context: context,
          delegate: SearchPage<Entry>(
            items: entries.entries,
            searchLabel: MyLocalizations.of(context).journalListSearchEntries,
            suggestion: Center(
              child: Text(MyLocalizations.of(context).journalListFilterEntries),
            ),
            failure: JournalEmpty(
              'lib/assets/emojis/no_items.png',
              MyLocalizations.of(context).journalListNoEntriesFound,
            ),
            filter: (entry) {
              List<String> filterOn = List<String>();
              filterOn.add(entry.title);
              if (entry.tags != null) {
                entry.tags.forEach((tag) => filterOn.add(tag));
              }
              return filterOn;
            },
            builder: (entry) => InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => JournalEntryView(entry),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: EntryCard1(
                entry,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          size: 30,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  void closeDrawer() {
    setState(() {
      widget.transformData.xOffset = 0;
      widget.transformData.yOffset = 0;
      widget.transformData.scaleFactor = 1;
      widget.isDrawerOpen = false;
    });
  }

  bool isDateChoosenValid() {
    return dateTimeSet.compareTo(DateTime.now()) < 1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    appDataModel = Provider.of<AppDataProvider>(context).appDataModel;

    return AnimatedContainer(
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
        widget.transformData.xOffset,
        widget.transformData.yOffset,
        0,
      )
        ..scale(widget.transformData.scaleFactor)
        ..rotateY(widget.isDrawerOpen ? -0.5 : 0),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          widget.isDrawerOpen ? 25 : 0.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (widget.isDrawerOpen) {
            closeDrawer();
          }
        },
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          child: Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        widget.isDrawerOpen
                            ? IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_back,
                                  size: 30,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  closeDrawer();
                                },
                              )
                            : IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.menu,
                                  size: 30,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    widget.transformData.xOffset = 260;
                                    widget.transformData.yOffset = 150;
                                    widget.transformData.scaleFactor = 0.7;
                                    widget.isDrawerOpen = true;
                                  });
                                }),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              Constants.APP_NAME,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 28,
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        _buildSearchEntryWidget(context)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  _buildCalenderStrip(context),
                  _buildEntryList(context),
                ],
              ),
              floatingActionButtonLocation:
                  FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
              floatingActionButton: isDateChoosenValid()
                  ? OpenContainer(
                      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                      closedBuilder: (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) =>
                          FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: null,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.edit,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        tooltip:
                            MyLocalizations.of(context).journalListAddEntry,
                        backgroundColor: isDateChoosenValid()
                            ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                            : Colors.grey[500],
                        elevation: 8.0,
                      ),
                      closedShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                      openBuilder: (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) {
                        final entry = Entry(
                          entryDate: dateTimeSet,
                          images: List<Object>(),
                          tags: List<String>(),
                        );
                        return JournalEntryView(entry);
                      },
                      tappable: isDateChoosenValid(),
                    )
                  : SizedBox()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomDayBuilder extends DayTileBuilder {
  final List<Entry> entries;
  CustomDayBuilder(this.entries);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, DateTime date, onTap) {
    Entry entry = entries.firstWhere(
      (entryInEntries) => DateFormat.yMMMd()
          .format(entryInEntries.entryDate)
          .contains(DateFormat.yMMMd().format(date)),
      orElse: () => Entry(),
    );
    return CustomDateTile(
      date: date,
      entry: entry,
      calendarroState: Calendarro.of(context),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class JournalEntryView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Entry entry;

  JournalEntryView(this.entry);

  @override
  _JournalEntryScreenState createState() => _JournalEntryScreenState();
}

class _JournalEntryScreenState extends State<JournalEntryView> {
  GlobalKey _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Entry entry = widget.entry;
    Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .setEntryContext(entry, context);
    return Hero(
      tag: '${entry.entryDate}${entry.id}',
      child: Form(
        child: Builder(
          builder: (ctx) {
            return WillPopScope(
              child: Scaffold(
                key: _scaffoldKey,
                resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                appBar: AppBar(
                  actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                  iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Form.of(ctx).save();
                        if (!Form.of(ctx).validate()) {
                          return;
                        }

                        if (Provider.of<EmojiListProvider>(context,
                                    listen: false)
                                .getChosenFeeling ==
                            null) {
                          _showFormError(
                            MyLocalizations.of(context).journalEntryNeedMood,
                          );
                          return;
                        } else {
                          entry.feelingOnEntry = entry.getFeeling(
                              Provider.of<EmojiListProvider>(context,
                                      listen: false)
                                  .getChosenFeeling
                                  .url);
                        }

                        if (entry.time == null) {
                          entry.time = DateFormat.Hm().format(DateTime.now());
                        }

                        entry.weather = 'Sunny';
                        Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false)
                            .saveEntry();
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.save,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 25,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  shadowColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  bottomOpacity: 0.0,
                ),
                body: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                            child: Container(
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    margin:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 5),
                                    child: Text(
                                      MyLocalizations.of(context)
                                          .journalEntryFeeling,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 22,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  ),
                                  FeelingsList(entry.feelingOnEntry),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 115),
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(80),
                          ),
                          child: EntryScreenData(entry),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              onWillPop: () {
                Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .clearEntryContext();
                Provider.of<EmojiListProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .setEmojiList();
                Navigator.pop(context);
                return;
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showFormError(String errorText) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[400],
      content: Text(errorText),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class EntryScreenData extends StatefulWidget {
  final Entry entry;
  List<Object> images;

  EntryScreenData(this.entry);

  @override
  _EntryScreenDataState createState() => _EntryScreenDataState();
}

class _EntryScreenDataState extends State<EntryScreenData> {
  final SettingsDataModel settingsDataModel =
      SettingsDataModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(sharedPrefs.settingsData));
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;

  DateTime datePicked;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _titleController.dispose();
    _descriptionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.entry.weather == null) {
      widget.entry.weather = 'Sunny';
    }

    _titleController.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: widget.entry.title != null ? widget.entry.title : '',
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
        offset: widget.entry.title != null ? widget.entry.title.length : 0,
      ),
    );

    _descriptionController.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: widget.entry.description != null ? widget.entry.description : '',
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
        offset: widget.entry.description != null
            ? widget.entry.description.length
            : 0,
      ),
    );

    widget.entry.entryDate != null
        ? datePicked = widget.entry.entryDate
        : datePicked = DateTime.now();

    widget.entry.tags != null
        ? widget.entry.tags = widget.entry.tags
        : widget.entry.tags = List<dynamic>();

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<String> getImage(int type) async {
    PickedFile pickedImage = await ImagePicker().getImage(
        source: type == 1 ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery,
        imageQuality: 50);
    return pickedImage.path;
  }

  _imgFromCamera() async {
    final imagePath = await getImage(1);
    Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .addImageToEntry(imagePath);
  }

  // HERE FOR INSTANCE IS WHERE I@M MAKING A CHANGE TO THE ENTRY THAT SHOWS ON THE LIST
  _imgFromGallery() async {
    final imagePath = await getImage(2);
    Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .addImageToEntry(imagePath);
  }

  
  Widget _buildTagList() {
    return Container(
      height: 71,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Text(MyLocalizations.of(context).entryScreenTags,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
          ),
          Consumer<EntryProvider>(
            builder: (context, entryProvider, child) => CreateHashtags(
              entryProvider.getEntry.tags,
              _addTag,
              _removeTag,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addTag(String tagText) {
    Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false).addTagToEntry(tagText);
  }

  void _removeTag(int index) {
    Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false).removeTagAt(index);
  }

  void _removeImage(int index) {
    Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false).removeImageAt(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              EntryMetaTags(widget.entry, _getAddressFromLatLng),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: _presentDatePicker,
                      child: Text(
                        DateFormat.yMMMd().format(
                          widget.entry.entryDate != null
                              ? widget.entry.entryDate
                              : DateTime.now(),
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                    ),
                    if (widget.entry.id != null)
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _showDeleteDialog(context);
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: TextFormField(
                  onSaved: (String title) {
                    Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .getEntry
                        .title = title;
                  },
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                  controller: _titleController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: MyLocalizations.of(context).entryScreenEnterTitle,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 190,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: TextFormField(
                  onSaved: (String description) {
                    Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .getEntry
                        .description = description;
                  },
                  validator: (description) {
                    if (description.isEmpty) {
                      return MyLocalizations.of(context)
                          .entryScreenEnterDescriptionWarn;
                    }

                    return null;
                  },
                  maxLines: 8,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                  controller: _descriptionController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText:
                        MyLocalizations.of(context).entryScreenEnterDescription,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
              _buildTagList(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 3,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      MyLocalizations.of(context).entryScreenImages,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Consumer<EntryProvider>(
                builder: (context, entryProvider, child) => ImageList(
                  entryProvider.getEntry.images,
                  _removeImage,
                  _showPicker,
                  _showImageDialog,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using the Bloc Pattern, it uses streams to update the ui. Provider is mainly use for providing data across multiple screens. Since it has that bug that updates both properties, you might want to try bloc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, objects are passed by reference. Therefore, you are modifying the same object. Since [there is no reflection in Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150), you cannot really make a copy automatically.

One way around the issue is implementing your own [copyWith](https://developer.school/dart-flutter-what-does-copywith-do/) method. This is what Flutter does internally in the case of styles, for example.

Update: it is important to note that List and Map are passed by reference as well. Therefore you need to use either [List.from](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List/List.from.html) or the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) in your own implementation of `copyWith`.

Example:

```
Entry(
 images: images ?? List.from(this.images),
);
```

Comment: I don't know why "Yes, objects are passed by reference. Therefore, you are modifying the same object." is so hard for me to get. I guess other languages and frameworks coddle developers to some degree. Okay, I'm going to try the copyWith. It has just been such a huge blocker for me to date and I couldn't understand why it wasn't working.

Comment: It means that the object itself is not being copied, only the memory address pointing to it. But since the copy of the address points to the same place in the memory, the same object is being modified.

Comment: Oh, I get what it means, I just don't get why the Dart/Flutter engineers did it this way. But thank you anyway for your explanation. I tried the implementation as you explained, what I noticed was at first it looks like it worked, but when I go back into the item card, I see the change still there, then when I press back, it's like it was on the original issue?

Comment: I've implemented the copyWith change into my code, I've added my Entry class and showed the edits made on the ListView. But I'm still getting the issue. Is the implemented way the correct way to do it?

Comment: Could you please share the code for the part where you actually make changes to the `Entry`? Is it in `EntryScreenData`? Also, what kind of changes do you make? Just a note, to make code more concise, you can just use `entry.copyWith()`, without parameters, if you don't want to override any value, just "copy" the object.

Comment: Riwen - Sorry for the delay, I added the EntryScreenData and removed some sections of the code in other areas which aren't important for the issue as it was getting long. I commented on a section where my images, 1 area that is causing the issue, to show what I'm doing. Also thanks for the note, I actually appreciate feedback on my code so if there is anything else please let me know :)

Comment: Okay, I think we may be onto something here. You are calling the `addImageToEntry` on the `EntryProvider`. However, it is *not* mutating the copied `Entry`, but rather the `_entry`. Now, I'm not sure where that comes from. I see it is set by the `setEntryContext` method, but I don't see any reference to it in your code. Where do you call that?

Comment: I removed the areas where I had Provider.of<EntryProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .setEntryContext(entry, context); being called as I didn't think it made a difference when I removed them. But it's in the JournalList and the JournalEntry. Thanks so much for digging into this with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227842/discussion-between-riwen-and-smiffykmc).

Comment: Thanks for your time in helping me understand this! I'm going to go away and get my head around this somemore!